# Create Esri File GDB from DataTable .Net Core?

Tags: c#, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, .net

I have data stored in a database in PostgreSQL created and handled via EF with dbContext in .Net Core. I need to export some tables into FileGDB using opensource libraries (I don't want to restrict users to use ESRI licence). Ideally, I would like to do it programmatically, without a need of having extra dependencies eg. storing/calling ogr2ogr.exe via cmd.

Things I tried:

1. [**NetTopologySuite.IO.GDB**](http://wsdot-gis.github.io/NetTopologySuiteDoxygen/docs/html/class_net_topology_suite_1_1_i_o_1_1_g_d_b_reader.html) - I saw that NetTopologySuite have some support for GDB, but when I tried to access it, it seems like is missing for .Net Core.

   var test = new NetTopologySuite.IO.GDB();
   [image]
2. [**Esri.ArcGISRuntime**](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcgis-runtime/) - it seems like this SDK is missing create functionality. You can only read existing GDB from path or portal, but I need to create a new one.
3. [**file-geodatabase-api**](https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api/tree/master/FileGDB_API_1.5.1) - It looks like is for .NetFramework only, I am not sure if it's supported in .Net Core 3.1. There is no NuGet package available and I couldn't find a good example or documentation of how I can use it.

Is there any opensource support for .Net Core DataTable and ESRI Geodatabase?